# how to programmatically share a "listed" video with a list of users (email addresses)?

Tags: youtube-api

How can one, using YouTube APIs, programmatically share a "listed" video with a list of users (email addresses)?   Effectively a bulk share.  An example in javascript format would be grea.

Comment: How do you do that via the UI?

Comment: one by one share to each via email address

Comment: can you explain more on what do you mean by share. do you mean you dont want to have your code share it with email list and you want youtube to share this with email list?

Comment: when you 'share' you given the person access rights to view your private video - so by share I mean given them permission/rights to view a private video

Answer (score -1):

I think you need server side JavaScript or client side JavaScript API.
YouTube doesn't have share API for emailing. It  only works when you are logged in and click share button.It is done for preventing misuse of sharing with a bot.
So write a code and run it with list of users you want to send.Make sure they don't report your video.
Node.js code

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'yourpassword'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
  to: 'myfriend@yahoo.com',
  subject: 'Please find my you tube link',
  text: 'youtube url'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

Comment: the object is to update the details of the video in youtube to add the individuals to have access rights to the video, and how to use the Google YouTube API to do this.  I don't see how sending an email relates to this?

Comment: @Greg I think the subject and title says how to programmatically share a “listed” video with a list of users (email addresses)?
 So he has kListed a video and he wants to write a program to share it to their email. you cannot share or mass send email from youtube api.

Comment: it seems that way.  Very difficult to use youtube as a means to share family (restricted) videos it seems...was ok with google circles...I don't want to have to manually share each video to my different family members etc so just trying to automate it...  Maybe youtube isn't the right platform for this scenario..